# Docker ModuleNotFoundError even though this module is not included in code anymore

Tags: python, docker, flask-cors

I have written a Flask API which I want to run in a docker container. However, `Error: While importing "api", an ImportError was raised:` keeps coming up even though the module which is not found is no longer in the code.

After the error occurred, I stopped, removed and restarted the Docker container to run the Flask Api:

```
docker stop privacy_api
docker rm privacy_api
docker build -t privacy_api_image .
docker run -dit --name=privacy_api -e FLASK_APP=api.py -p 5000:5000 -v main_api:/app --network privacy-network privacy_api_image
5963fb7fa194d6710ae5e713d2060bd0be5338b04636bf306b78bda4bb596524

docker logs -f privacy_api
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
* Serving Flask app "api.py"
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

    Error: While importing "api", an ImportError was raised:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
        __import__(module_name)
      File "/app/api.py", line 2, in <module>
        from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'
```

This is my api.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
import MySQLdb
import json
import logging
import formscripts as priv
import databreach
from datetime import datetime
import pytz #needs to be added to Docker!

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_db_connection():
    cursor=None
    if not cursor:
        connection = MySQLdb.connect("privacy-mysql", "root", "DockerPasswort!", "privacydatabase")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
    return cursor, connection

@app.route('/data_remove', methods=["POST"])
def data_takedown():
    print("in takedown")
    cursor, connection = get_db_connection()
    data = request.get_json()
    email_login=False
    email_pw=""
    title = data["title"]
    firstname = data["firstname"]
    lastname = data["lastname"]
    suffix = data["suffix"]
    email = data["email"]
    phone_num = data["phone_num"]
    street = data["street"]
    apt = data["apt"]
    city = data["city"]
    state = data["state"]
    country = data["country"]
    zip_code = data["zip_code"]
    cc_last4 = data["cc_last4"]
    data_del_msg = data["data_del_msg"]
    deviceAdID = data["deviceAdID"]
    privacyReg = data["privacyReg"]
    if "email_pw" in data:
        email_login=True
        email_pw=data["email_pw"]
    #############################################
    ####### privacy form script functions #######
    #############################################
    if email_login==True:
        email_result = requests.post('http://localhost:5001/email', json={
    "from_email": email,
    "password": email_pw,
    "to_email": "consumeradvo@acxiom.com",
    "subject": "Acxiom Opt out request for: "+firstname+" "+lastname+" ("+email+")",
    "message": "Dear Acxiom Team, I would like you to remove my information. This is my name: "+firstname+" "+lastname+" "+suffix+". This is my phone_number: "+phone_num+", my email: "+email+ ". This is my address: Street: "+street+", Apartment: "+apt+", City: "+city+", State: "+state+", Zip: "+zip_code
    })
        #Feel free to test whether it works for you with gmail (it should if you change the commenting for the server in send_email.py) but somehow it doesn't for me
        """
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/email', json={
            "from_email": "alexander.farr@gmail.com",
            "password": "Password",
            "to_email": "alexander.farr@hotmail.de",
            "subject": "subject test",
            "message": "body test"
        })
        """

    adColony = priv.adColony_DoNotSSP(email, firstname, lastname, privacyReg,
                                      deviceAdID)
    petco = priv.petco_delete(firstname, lastname, email, phone_num)
    linkedIn = priv.linkedIn_DataDelete(firstname, lastname, email,
                                        data_del_msg)
    chipotle = priv.chipotle_delete(firstname, lastname, email, phone_num,
                                    cc_last4)
    pipl = priv.pipl_delete(firstname, lastname, email, phone_num,
                            data_del_msg)
    asl = priv.asl_DD_formfill(firstname, lastname, street, city, state,
                               zip_code, phone_num, email)
    bestBuy = priv.bestBuy_DD_formfill(firstname, lastname, country, street,
                                       city, zip_code, phone_num, email)
    booking = priv.booking_DD_formfill(email)
    analyticsIQ=priv.analyticsIQ_DD_formfill(firstname, lastname, country, address, city, state, zipcode, email)
    asl=priv.asl_DD_formfill(firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zipcode, phone, email)

    ############
    #####TODO test whether next three functions are working and otherwise remove (also from database)#####
    ##########
    atlantic=priv.atlantic_DD_formfill(california_resident, email, zipcode)
    instantCheckmate=priv.instantCheckmate_DD_formfill(firstname, lastname, city)
    intelius=priv.intelius_DD_formfill(firstname, lastname, cityState)
    ####### Check for data breach  #######
    databreach=request_answer(email)
    ####### Insert into database   #######
    tz_LA = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    datetime_LA = datetime.now(tz_LA)
    timstamp=datetime_LA.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    sql='INSERT INTO privacydb (timstamp, adColony, asl, analyticsiq, bestbuy, booking, chipotle, instantcheckmate, intelius, linkedin, petco, pipl, atlantic, databreach) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
    cursor.execute(sql, [timstamp, adColony, asl, analyticsIQ, bestBuy, booking, chipotle, instantCheckmate, intelius, linkedIn, petco, pipl, atlantic, databreach])
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    #TODO OUTPUT sending email
    return json.dumps({
        "adColony": adColony,
        "asl": asl,
        "analyticsIQ": analyticsIQ,
        "best buy": bestBuy,
        "booking.com": booking,
        "chipotle": chipotle,
        "instantCheckmate": instantCheckmate,
        "intelius": intelius,
        "linkedIn": linkedIn,
        "petco": petco,
        "pipl": pipl,
        "atlantic": atlantic,
        "databreach": databreach
    }), 200
```

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements-main-api.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["flask"]
CMD ["run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

This is the `requirements-main-api.txt file`:

```
flask==1.1.1
mysqlclient==1.4.6
selenium
requests
pytz
```

I don't understand the error since Cors is not in the api.py file anymore.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `-v main_api:/app` option.

What this does is it takes the contents of the `main_api` named volume and mounts it over `/app`.  Even if your Dockerfile updates the code in the image, this run-time option hides that change and uses the existing contents of the volume instead.

This apparently worked in the past because the first time (only) you run the container, the contents of the image are copied into a new empty volume.  If there's already content in the volume, Docker will not overwrite potentially important user data, so if you try to put your application code into a named volume, you will be running a fixed old version of your code.

Comment: Is there anyway that I could share the content of the app? I was trying to get the source code of deployed containers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Flask-Cors==1.10.3` to your requirements-main-api.txt

If you already remove all the dependencies call for this library then be sure to save the file, and run the dockerfile again with `--no-cache` flag

You can also remove previous image with `docker rmi <ImageNameOrID>` and if you want to clean up the docker Daemon system : `docker system prune -a`

Comment: Why do I need to add `Flask-Cors==1.10.3` when I don't import it in `api.py`?

Comment: it seems that you do import it in line 2....that what the error says
If the code that you post (your api.py file that you show here) is also the "/app/api.py" file...then you removed the line 2 which used to be 

"from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin"

if you removed it so you do not need Flask-Cors anymore and you can also remove it form the requirements

Comment: I used to but this is not included in the api.py file anymore so I am confused why it still gives me the error even with the `--no-cache` flat attached

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but have you save the new api.py ?
If you dont mind about the images you already have in your system you can also remove the previous image `docker rmi privacy_api_image` or even more rude way : 
`docker system prune --all`

Comment: Thanks, I had saved it and did docker system prune already but will try yours

Comment: It seems to still be cached even after docker `rmi privacy_api_image` and with `--no-cache` flag